# C++ stackless coroutines: Will the stack ptr be set to the heap-allocated coro frame?

Tags: c++, stack, heap-memory, c++-coroutine

I'm just getting into C++ coroutines and I want to build up my understanding on how it all works.

I heard that C++ coroutines are stackless, which means the coroutine frame will be allocated on the heap. Now when starting or resuming the coroutine I have two options: I could copy all frame data to the callers stack, or I could just move my stackpointer to the frame which I suppose would be more efficient? How is it done internally?

This is what I have in mind:

[image]

Please correct me if I'm wrong. In the left variant, the stack pointer is moved to the heap allocated coroutine frame. The right variant just copies everything next to the caller stack. If my understanding is correct, the left variant would be a lot faster. Is that the way coroutines are implemented in C++? In the other case the time complexity would grow with the size complexity of the frame, which would mean coroutines that push a lot of material to the "stack" would be increasingly slower.

Comment: Internally, it's neither. The variables are simply kept in the coroutine frame and accessed through the coroutine frame. You can think of all the variables as members of the coroutine frame object.

Comment: "*Now when starting or resuming the coroutine I have two options*" **You** have zero options, as you have absolutely no control over that. Well, not entirely; you *could* use a stack allocator to allocate the coroutine on the stack by using specific coroutine machinery in your promise type, but you really shouldn't. And either way, you don't "move" it anywhere afterwards.

Comment: Stack pointer can't point to the heap, because the coroutine can call other functions, and the heap doesn't have space for their stack frames.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "*the heap doesn't have space for their stack frames*" Which is probably why a coroutine would be given both the current stack's pointer and its actual "heap-allocated" stack frame pointer.

Comment: @RaymondChen That would mean that in a coroutine, stack variables are indirected once and handles to heap containers would be indirected twice. This would make coroutines significantly slower than normal functions, no?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Couldn't you just jump back for ordinary function calls?

Comment: Surprise: Even in non-coroutines, stack variables are indirected once (through the stack pointer register).

Comment: @RaymondChen Interesting. That would probably use the LEA instruction on x86? Do you have any sources? I would like to read up on that. In any case, does that mean that access performance for non-coroutines and coroutines stays the same?

Comment: This is all implementation detail, so there are no "sources" aside from the compiler itself. The standard does not require any specific implementation of coroutines. You can use sites like gcc.godbolt.org to explore how compilers implement coroutines, or you can try reading the compiler source code.